# How to detect via regex numbers and +,-,/,* symbols?

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex, and I'm looking to create the expression which would consist:

- numbers
- symbols +,-,/,*

I was thinking about mixing \p{Punct} with \d, but I am not sure if this is the best way.

How to define the regex in the best possible way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what's "best possible way" is for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the both patterns inside a character class `"[\\p{Punct}\\d]"` or make it repeat one or more times by adding `+` quantifier next to that character class like `"[\\p{Punct}\\d]+"` so that it would match one or more punctuation chars or digits.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to obtain digits and symbols separatly, so you can do it with a simple alternation (no need to use the `Punct` class, use a custom character class):

```
[0-9]+|[-+/*]
```

You can reduce the regex engine work like this (to quickly skip all that is not a digit or an operator):

```
(?=[0-9+/*-])(?:[0-9]+|[-+/*])
```

Where `(?=[0-9+/*-])` is an assertion that means *followed by a digit or `+`, `/`, `*`, `-`*